# How to remove django crispy form field validation error?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I would like to override the errors in crispy forms to hide the default crispy form  field(username) validation error because I am using clean method for validation already.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz4Gp.png)

```
class AddEmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddEmployeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', ]:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = True

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_action = '/add_employee/'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_show_errors = True
        self.helper.error_text_inline = False
        # NEW:
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-5'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('first_name', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('last_name', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('username', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('email', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('password', css_class='input-sm'),
            # NEW:
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AddEmployeeForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        if User.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email already exists.')
        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists.')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

In template I have used this only.:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% crispy form %}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain the issue a bit more, add part of code which you think is causing the issue or add a code snippet which would be similar to your code and can reproduce the error. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know about how to ask a better question

Comment: check image you can see there are two errors one on top and other one is below the field. I want to remove error below the field because I am using clean method.

Comment: Like i said, without the code, we cant understand whats happening, unless someone here knows what you're exactly doing and might have answer

Comment: The error being shown under the input is due to the things happing inside the html, please also add, the html snippet of form being used

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `form_show_errors` parameter being passwed to `helper` to  `False`

i.e. replace the line

`self.helper.form_show_errors = True`

to

`self.helper.form_show_errors = False`

Your new `AddEmployeeForm` class will look as follows

```
class AddEmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddEmployeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for fieldname in ['username', ]:
            self.fields[fieldname].help_text = None

        for key in self.fields:
            self.fields[key].required = True

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_action = '/add_employee/'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_show_errors = False
        self.helper.error_text_inline = False
        # NEW:
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-5'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('first_name', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('last_name', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('username', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('email', css_class='input-sm'),
            Field('password', css_class='input-sm'),
            # NEW:
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary')
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AddEmployeeForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        if User.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email already exists.')
        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists.')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: I thought thats what you are asking, also, if you dont want to use crispy forms validations and its ease of use, why do you want to use it at all? Just use a normal html form than crispy forms

Comment: This works but I see a red borderline in that particular textinput box! Can you please tell me what to do ?